# Jquery UI Datepicker not working for requiredfieldvalidator C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I am facing a strange problem in the aspx page of my C# applicaton. I am using UI Datepicker for a date selector textbox control along with requiredfieldvalidator for that text control. During value entry, datepicker is not showing the calendar until I remove the requiredfieldvalidator. Please advice me what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Pinaki Karuri

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI Date-picker is using JavaScript, you have to debug properly.

Reason may be :
1. Another JavaScript error may have occurred before date picker script.

USE Mozilla Error console add-ons for testing getting real specific problem.

Also sometime it happens with field name. Also you should not use field name attribute=name or date.